# Script Getting Stuck While Sorting Files Using Grep

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

So I currently am working on a matching script that does a few things:

1. Takes a list of keywords
2. For each individual keyword, look through the directory for grep matches
3. For each grep match, copy and paste the file into a "Sorted/{keyword}" directory

The functionality seems to be fine with a couple of issues.

1. When I run the script, it seems to get stuck on the first iteration of the loop until I press Ctrl-C, then it spits out a lot of the console messages I would expect to be receiving throughout the process.
2. It takes absurdly long to finish (which might be something that there's no way around, but any optimization advice would be greatly appreciated).

Little note, I am using [pdfgrep](https://pdfgrep.org/). It seems to be pretty functionally the same, just thought it was worth mentioning.

I'm pretty new to scripting, so please feel free to critique and correct.

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Keyword list
keywords=(
    "Keyword1"
    "Keyword2"
    "Keyword3"
);

mkdir "$HOME/Sorted";
echo "Matching list of keywords/phrases ... (${#keywords[@]}) in length...";
for ((i = 0; i < ${#keywords[@]}; i++))
do
    echo "Matching ${keywords[$i]}...";
    mkdir "$HOME/Sorted/${keywords[$i]}";
    pdfgrep -lir "${keywords[$i]}" $HOME/PDFs/* | xargs -I{} cp {} -t $HOME/Sorted/"${keywords[$i]}";
done

echo "Finished that matching session... ";
echo "###########################";
echo "Unable to match:"
find $HOME/Sorted/ -type d -empty -printf "%P\n";
find $HOME/Sorted/ -type d -empty -delete;
```

Comment: the syntax of `for` in [Fravodona's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72849958/13982210) is cleaner to read (and also write!); another thing you might want to try is positional command line arguments. given `command word1 word2 word3`, inside the script you can access `$1` as word1 and so on. `"${@}"` is all cli args, with each arg wrapped in `"` (safety!).

Comment: And a slight aside: are you sure you want to store e.g. 3 copies of a PDF if it happens to match 3 keywords?

Comment: @tink I wasn't sure of another way to go about it. I added in a section that checks for duplicate file copies afterwards in a sort of "cleanup" fashion.

Comment: `pdfgrep -irlZ | sort -u -z | xargs -0` :) `sort -u` (`-z` for \0 aka null termination) should remove duplicate listings from pdfgrep before xargs is run. combine with the linking tip from Fravadona's answer for exxxtra speeed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` is probably the culprit; you should add the `--no-run-if-empty` (aka `-r`) option and specify the delimiter to be `\0` (in combination with `pdfgrep -lZ`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

keywords=(
    "Keyword1"
    "Keyword2"
    "Keyword3"
)

for kw in "${keywords[@]}"
do
    printf 'Matching keyword: %q\n' "$kw"
    folder="$HOME"/Sorted/"$kw"
    mkdir -p "$folder" || exit 1
    pdfgrep -irlZ "$kw" "$HOME"/PDFs/ | xargs -0 -r cp -t "$folder/"
done

echo "Unmatched keywords:"
find "$HOME"/Sorted/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -delete -printf "\t%P\n"
```

**Aside:** You could create symbolic or even hard links to the PDF (with `... | xargs -0 -r ln -s -t "$folder/"`) instead of copying them; that'll be faster and save disk space.

Comment: would also help to mention that `-r` is the same as `--no-run-if-empty` :) it's not apparent

Comment: @kevinnls I just added a mention of it

Comment: Awesome! That solved the issue completely. Thanks.

Comment: @Fravadona i think you missed the target in the ln command. `ln ... -t "${folder}"`?

Comment: @kevinnls my bad, corrected

Comment: no worries :) thank you for teaching me the syntax. i have been wondering for a long time how i could do fs operations with xargs. and now i know!

Comment: @kevinnls This one is GNU specific; with BSD's `xargs` you would do it differently

Comment: interesting. thanks for the addendum :) i'll keep that in mind